# Playing music with the IBM-PC speaker

Tags: audio, assembly, x86-16, tasm, dosbox

I'm working on a lab project, and I ran into a little problem. I already have written some code to make musical notes play, that part seems to work.  The problem I'm having is that I handle the 'm' key for my music, and when I press it, the music plays, as it should.  However, I need to handle another key or button to PAUSE the music and when it is pressed again, (a second time) the music should continue to play, right where it left off.  I really cannot figure out how to handle the second key press, so the music will be continued, and not started over again.  I am working in GUI Turbo Assembler, and this is the core of the code I have so far:

```
 TITLE   MUSIC.EXE
 STACKSG SEGMENT PARA    STACK   'Stack'
 DW  128 DUP(?)
 STACKSG ENDS
 DATASG  SEGMENT PARA    'Data'

 DATASG  ENDS
 CODESG  SEGMENT PARA    'Code'
 ASSUME  CS:CODESG, DS:DATASG, SS:STACKSG, ES:NOTHING
SOUND   PROC
  PUSH    AX
  PUSH    BX
  PUSH    CX
  PUSH    DX
  PUSH    DI
  MOV AL, 0B6H
  OUT 43H, AL
  MOV DX, 14H
  MOV AX, 4F38H
  DIV DI
  OUT 42H, AL
  MOV AL, AH
  OUT 42H, AL
  IN  AL, 61H
  MOV AH, AL
  OR  AL, 3
  OUT 61H, AL
L1: MOV CX, 6801
L2: LOOP    L2
  DEC BX
  JNZ L1
  MOV AL, AH
  OUT 61H, AL
  POP DI
  POP DX
  POP CX
  POP BX
  POP AX
  RET
SOUND   ENDP
MAIN    PROC
  MOV BX, 50
L3: MOV AH, 0
  INT 16H
  CMP AL, 'x'
  JE  EXIT
  CMP AL, 'q'
  JE  DO 
  CMP AL, 'w'
  JE  RE
  CMP AL, 'e'
  JE  MI
  CMP AL, 'r'
  JE  FA
  CMP AL, 't'
  JE  SOL
  CMP AL, 'y'
  JE  LA
  CMP AL, 'u'
  JE  CI
  CMP AL, 'm'
  JE  MEL
  JNZ L3
DO: MOV DI, 131
  CALL    SOUND
  JMP L3
RE: MOV DI, 147
  CALL    SOUND
  JMP L3
MI: MOV DI, 165
  CALL    SOUND
  JMP L3
FA: MOV DI, 175
  CALL    SOUND
  JMP L3
SOL:    MOV DI, 196
  CALL    SOUND
  JMP L3
LA: MOV DI, 220
  CALL    SOUND
  JMP L3
CI: MOV DI, 247
  CALL    SOUND
  JMP L3
EXIT:   MOV AH, 00H
  MOV AL, 03H
  INT 10H
  MOV AX, 4C00H
  INT 21H
  RET

MEL:    
L4: LOOP L4
  MOV DI, 147
  CALL    SOUND
  MOV DI, 147
  CALL    SOUND
  MOV DI, 147
  CALL    SOUND
  MOV DI, 196
  CALL    SOUND
  MOV DI, 196
  CALL    SOUND
  MOV DI, 175
  CALL    SOUND
  MOV DI, 165
  CALL    SOUND
  MOV DI, 220
  CALL    SOUND
  MOV DI, 220
  CALL    SOUND
  MOV DI, 196
  CALL    SOUND
  MOV DI, 147
  CALL    SOUND
  MOV DI, 147
  CALL    SOUND
  MOV DI, 147
  CALL    SOUND
  MOV DI, 147
  CALL    SOUND
  JMP L4

MAIN    ENDP
CODESG  ENDS
END MAIN
```

Comment: You really should state which assembly language i.e. architecture you're using, and flag your question accordingly.

Comment: *GUI Turbo Assembler* - this one: http://sourceforge.net/projects/guitasm8086? Then please add the tags [tasm] and [dosbox] by editing the question.

Comment: ty for correcting, im just a new on this site

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Happy New Year @everybody!

```
; Name:             music.asm
; Assemble:         tasm.exe music.asm
; Link:             tlink.exe music.obj
; Run in DOSBox:    music.exe

a0      =   43388       ;   27.5000 hz
ais0    =   40953       ;   29.1353 hz
h0      =   38655       ;   30.8677 hz
c1      =   36485       ;   32.7032 hz
cis1    =   34437       ;   34.6479 hz
d1      =   32505       ;   36.7081 hz
dis1    =   30680       ;   38.8909 hz
e1      =   28958       ;   41.2035 hz
f1      =   27333       ;   43.6536 hz
fis1    =   25799       ;   46.2493 hz
g1      =   24351       ;   48.9995 hz
gis1    =   22984       ;   51.9130 hz
a1      =   21694       ;   55.0000 hz
ais1    =   20477       ;   58.2705 hz
h1      =   19327       ;   61.7354 hz
c2      =   18243       ;   65.4064 hz
cis2    =   17219       ;   69.2957 hz
d2      =   16252       ;   73.4162 hz
dis2    =   15340       ;   77.7817 hz
e2      =   14479       ;   82.4069 hz
f2      =   13666       ;   87.3071 hz
fis2    =   12899       ;   92.4986 hz
g2      =   12175       ;   97.9989 hz
gis2    =   11492       ;  103.8260 hz
a2      =   10847       ;  110.0000 hz
ais2    =   10238       ;  116.5410 hz
h2      =   9664        ;  123.4710 hz
c3      =   9121        ;  130.8130 hz
cis3    =   8609        ;  138.5910 hz
d3      =   8126        ;  146.8320 hz
dis3    =   7670        ;  155.5630 hz
e3      =   7240        ;  164.8140 hz
f3      =   6833        ;  174.6140 hz
fis3    =   6450        ;  184.9970 hz
g3      =   6088        ;  195.9980 hz
gis3    =   5746        ;  207.6520 hz
a3      =   5424        ;  220.0000 hz
ais3    =   5119        ;  233.0820 hz
h3      =   4832        ;  246.9420 hz
c4      =   4561        ;  261.6260 hz
cis4    =   4305        ;  277.1830 hz
d4      =   4063        ;  293.6650 hz
dis4    =   3835        ;  311.1270 hz
e4      =   3620        ;  329.6280 hz
f4      =   3417        ;  349.2280 hz
fis4    =   3225        ;  369.9940 hz
g4      =   3044        ;  391.9950 hz
gis4    =   2873        ;  415.3050 hz
a4      =   2712        ;  440.0000 hz
ais4    =   2560        ;  466.1640 hz
h4      =   2416        ;  493.8830 hz
c5      =   2280        ;  523.2510 hz
cis5    =   2152        ;  554.3650 hz
d5      =   2032        ;  587.3300 hz
dis5    =   1918        ;  622.2540 hz
e5      =   1810        ;  659.2550 hz
f5      =   1708        ;  698.4560 hz
fis5    =   1612        ;  739.9890 hz
g5      =   1522        ;  783.9910 hz
gis5    =   1437        ;  830.6090 hz
a5      =   1356        ;  880.0000 hz
ais5    =   1280        ;  932.3280 hz
h5      =   1208        ;  987.7670 hz
c6      =   1140        ; 1046.5000 hz
cis6    =   1076        ; 1108.7300 hz
d6      =   1016        ; 1174.6600 hz
dis6    =    959        ; 1244.5100 hz
e6      =    905        ; 1318.5100 hz
f6      =    854        ; 1396.9100 hz
fis6    =    806        ; 1479.9800 hz
g6      =    761        ; 1567.9800 hz
gis6    =    718        ; 1661.2200 hz
a6      =    678        ; 1760.0000 hz
ais6    =    640        ; 1864.6600 hz
h6      =    604        ; 1975.5300 hz
c7      =    570        ; 2093.0000 hz
cis7    =    538        ; 2217.4600 hz
d7      =    508        ; 2349.3200 hz
dis7    =    479        ; 2489.0200 hz
e7      =    452        ; 2637.0200 hz
f7      =    427        ; 2793.8300 hz
fis7    =    403        ; 2959.9600 hz
g7      =    380        ; 3135.9600 hz
gis7    =    359        ; 3322.4400 hz
a7      =    339        ; 3520.0000 hz
ais7    =    320        ; 3729.3100 hz
h7      =    302        ; 3951.0700 hz
c8      =    285        ; 4186.0100 hz

whole_note          = 1800
half_note_dot       = whole_note/2 + whole_note/4
half_note           = whole_note/2
quarter_note_dot    = whole_note/4 + whole_note/8
quarter_note        = whole_note/4
eighth_note         = whole_note/8
pause               = 30

LOCALS
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK

.DATA
div1 dd 14318180
div2 dd 786432000

AuldLangSyne dw 0,eighth_note
    dw g3,quarter_note
    dw c4,quarter_note_dot,h3,eighth_note,c4,quarter_note,e4,quarter_note
    dw d4,quarter_note_dot,c4,eighth_note,d4,quarter_note,e4,eighth_note,d4,eighth_note
    dw c4,quarter_note,0,pause,c4,quarter_note,e4,quarter_note,g4,quarter_note
    dw a4,half_note_dot,0,pause,a4,quarter_note
    dw g4,quarter_note_dot,e4,eighth_note,0,pause,e4,quarter_note,c4,quarter_note
    dw d4,quarter_note_dot,c4,eighth_note,d4,quarter_note,e4,eighth_note,d4,eighth_note
    dw c4,quarter_note_dot,a3,eighth_note,0,pause,a3,quarter_note,g3,quarter_note
    dw c4,half_note_dot,0,quarter_note,a4,quarter_note
    dw g4,quarter_note_dot,e4,eighth_note,0,pause,e4,quarter_note,c4,quarter_note
    dw d4,quarter_note_dot,c4,eighth_note,d4,quarter_note,a4,quarter_note
    dw g4,quarter_note_dot,e4,eighth_note,0,pause,e4,quarter_note,g4,quarter_note
    dw a4,half_note_dot,0,pause,a4,quarter_note
    dw g4,quarter_note_dot,e4,eighth_note,0,pause,e4,quarter_note,c4,quarter_note
    dw d4,quarter_note_dot,c4,eighth_note,d4,quarter_note,e4,eighth_note,d4,eighth_note
    dw c4,quarter_note_dot,a3,eighth_note,0,pause,a3,quarter_note,g3,quarter_note
    dw c4,half_note_dot
    dw 0,0

Welcome db "[p] Pause (any key for resuming) [r] Restart  [x] Exit $"

.CODE
.486

delay PROC NEAR ms:word     ; ARG on stack: delay in ms (granularity ~55 ms)
    push bp
    mov bp, sp
    sub sp, 4

    xor ax, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov edx, es:[046Ch]

    ; Ticks/sec: 14318180 / 12 / 65536 = 18.206785178403397675542331069912 -> 54.9254 mS

    fild word ptr ms
    fimul dword ptr div1
    fidiv dword ptr div2
    fistp dword ptr [bp-4]

    add edx, [bp-4]

    @@L1:
    mov eax, es:[046Ch]
    cmp eax, edx
    jb @@L1

    leave
    ret 2
delay ENDP

play PROC NEAR              ; ARG si: pointer to freq/duration pairs, end with 0/0
    mov di, si              ; Preserve it for the check_key routine

    @@L1:
    cmp word ptr [si], 0    ; No tone?
    je @@J1                 ; Yes: skip the sound blocks, just delay

    ; Set up frequency
    cli                     ; Don't disturb the setting sequence
    mov al, 0B6h
    out 43h, al
    mov ax, [si]
    out 42h, al
    mov al, ah
    out 42h, al
    sti

    in al, 61h              ; Speaker on
    or al, 03h
    out 61h, al

    @@J1:
    push word ptr [si+2]    ; Hold the tone for a certain while
    call delay

    in al, 61h              ; Speaker off
    and al, 0FCh
    out 61h, al

    add si, 4
    call check_key          ; DI: pointer for restart
    cmp word ptr [si+2], 0
    jne @@L1

    ret
play ENDP

check_key PROC              ; ARG di: pointer for restart
    mov ah, 1               ; Check keyboard
    int 16h
    jz @@done               ; No key -> return
    mov ah, 0               ; Get key
    int 16h

    @@K0:                   ; Pause
    cmp al, 'p'
    jne @@K1
    call @@pause
    @@K1:
    cmp al, 'P'
    jne @@K2
    @@pause:
    mov ah, 0
    int 16h
    push eighth_note
    call delay
    jmp @@K0

    @@K2:                   ; Exit
    cmp al, 'x'
    je @@exit
    cmp al, 'X'
    jne @@K3
    @@exit:
    mov ax, 4C00h
    int 21h

    @@K3:                   ; Restart
    cmp al, 'r'
    je @@restart
    cmp al, 'R'
    jne @@K4
    @@restart:
    mov si, di

    @@K4:                   ; Placeholder for further key checks
    @@done:
    ret
check_key ENDP

main PROC
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    mov ah, 9
    lea dx, Welcome
    int 21h

    lea si, AuldLangSyne
    call play

    mov ax, 4C00h
    int 21h
main ENDP

END main
```

Comment: Forgive me for the wrong edit. Now I've read about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auld_Lang_Syne#At_New_Year

Answer (score 3):

The best place for such a thing is the loop `L2`:

```
...
L1: MOV CX, 6801
L2:
    push ax             ; Preserve AX
    mov ah, 1           ; CHECK FOR KEYSTROKE
    int 16h
    jz done             ; No keystroke, no pause
    mov ah, 0           ; GET KEYSTROKE
    int 16h
    cmp al, 'p'         ; Key == 'p'?
    jnz done            ; No -> no action
    @J1:                ; Loop for pause
    pop ax              ; POP/PUSH: Get AX and store it
    push ax
    mov al, ah          ; Sound off
    out 61h, al
    mov ah, 0           ; GET KEYSTROKE (wait)
    int 16h
    cmp al, 'p'         ; Key == 'p'?
    jne @J1             ; No: continue with pause
    OR  AL, 3           ; Yes: sound on
    OUT 61H, AL
    done:
    pop ax              ; Restore AX

    LOOP L2
    DEC BX
    JNZ L1
...
```

A keystroke on <kbd>P</kbd> (lower case) switches the pause on and off.

Comment: yes it works with a tone sound(pitch). Cant understand why it does not work with a melody T_T

Comment: @AnnieSquare: I successfully tested it with 'm' on my DOSBox. Maybe I will tomorrow install *GUI Turbo Assembler* and test it there. The single tones are too short to be interruptable.

Comment: One more question: if i want to handle a button ('F') for reload from start my melody, i should do it in loop L2 too? if i do it in L3 it doesnt work, seems like it should be in L2.

Comment: im still trying to make a button that will reload my melody. Oh god, its not that easy -_-

Comment: @AnnieSquare: I would totally rearrange the program and create an array with tones. Then a loop can load this array and call `SOUND`. This loop can be interrupted for anything. E.g. for restarting the melody the pointer to the array has just to be resetted. And no! I won't program that for you! :-)

Comment: @rkhm, ty mate, u help me a lot! i will do it myself nya